# In CodeIgniter it says "Object not found"

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, syntax-error

I cant get access to the controller logins.php it gives 404 error.

HTML

```
<section id="butoes">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row rowCenter">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <h3><a href="<?=base_url()?>logins/">Login</a></h3>
        <a href="<?=base_url()?>logins/"><div class="sim-button btn button14">Login</div></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="sim-button btn button14">Register</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="sim-button btn button14">Recover Password</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Controller

```
function Logins extends CI_Controller
{
   function __construct()
   {
      parent::__construct();
   }

   function index()
   {
      $this->load->view('login_index');
   }
}
```

The page login_index exists in the views folder.

The login controller is in this path C:\xampp\htdocs\CI2\application\controllers\logins.php

Comment: why you are using two anchor tags for login?

Comment: `function Logins extends CI_Controller` ???

Comment: It probably can't find it because no `class` Logins exists. Have you tried replacing `function Logins extends CI_Controller` with `class Logins extends CI_Controller` ?

Comment: Share your htaccess file.

Comment: @kerbholz yes i try it now and it steal do the same error

Comment: @Adnanhaider here it is the .htaccess file
  
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /projFolder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /projFolder/index.php/$1 [L]

Comment: @DanishAli i was using two just to try if there is something bad but now i only have the button

Comment: "http://[::1]/CI2/logins 404 (Not Found)"         This is what it gives me on the Console of the broswer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

404 is the error code of page not found. It means you have wrong while writing your url wich it call the controller. I'll give you a solution how to check this one.

1. Check your base url in the `application/config/config.php` . Then you can see this code `$config['base_url']    = '';` . Make sure the contents of the array is the same as your web name.
2. Check your file `.htacces` in your base directory whether it exist or not. If no htaccess there, you need to write `index.php` after you write the `base_url()`.
3. Check the sensitive case. Make sure the name of your controller class as same as with your controller filename.
4. Check your controller url. Make sure you write the url with the true controller directory. For example, you have a controller in `application/controllers/login/Login.php`. You must write your url `<?php echo base_url(); ?>/login/Login` (it means you find the index method in the Login controller).

Comment: the first step is ok, the second step i change the .htaccess to "RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /projFolder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /projFolder/index.php/$1 [L]
"
the third step, the names are equal, the name of the controller is logins.php

  fourth, i check it a couple times and they are equal

Comment: @DanielLopes nice comment.

Comment: @GilianPratama sorry, this is my first time doing a question on stackoverflow :/

Comment: @DanielLopes its okay sir. my answer just for solving your problem. for the next step. what the url out when you click your `<a></a>`??

Comment: thanks my url when i click is "http://localhost/CI2/logins" now i have the problem solved what i did? I created an .htaccess filme on (in this case) CI2 folder and i put the next code:                                                                                                  RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

Answer (score 0):

If you do not set your base url then in application/config/config.php set your base url like this

```
$config['base_url'] = 'set-base-url';   

<section id="butoes">
<div class="container">
<div class="row rowCenter">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <h3><a href="<?php echo base_url('logins'); ?>">Login</a></h3>
    <a href="<?php echo base_url('logins'); ?>"><div class="sim-button btn button14">Login</div></a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="sim-button btn button14">Register</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="sim-button btn button14">Recover Password</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: On the Console that is what it says
 "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status logins of 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: have you set your base_url() ?

Comment: This is my 2nd application in CodeIgniter and i left it empty. In my 1st app is like this "$config['base_url'] = '';" and it gives no problems

Comment: you have to set your base url to use this function base_url()

Comment: what about your htaccess file and url helper?

Comment: the url helper is like this "$autoload['helper'] = array('url');" the base url is "$config['base_url'] = '';" because i'm using an local server.

Comment: i have edited my base_url to "$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/CI2/';" and now if i call the controller with index.php on url it works and i have de .htaccess with the same code as the codeigniter guide says to take out the index.php from the url https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html?highlight=htaccess

Answer (score 0):

> 1.- Check *application/config/config.php*
>
> $config['base_url] = '';
>
> example:
>
> $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/myproject/';

---

> 2.- Check **.htaccess** file in your root directory. you don´t write index.php. Here my configuration file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

> Check config.php file in application/config/ and change
>
> *$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';*
>
> to:
>
> $config['index_page'] = '';

---

> 3.- Finally the first letter always in capital letters in the controller

*Good luck !*

Comment: Thanks now if i call the controller with index.php on the url it works but i don't want to write that. My .htaccess has the same code as you post here

Comment: You have to modify a file named config.php in config folder in addition of .htaccess